# Emacs comint is truncating input

Tags: emacs

In Emacs sql mode or lisp mode connected to an inferior SQLi or Lisp process, there's a limit to how much data I can send to the process buffer in one go.  Over the limit some or all data is lost.

I've tried to find what the limit is by running a comint process which simply reads input and echoes it.  The limit seems to be around 760 characters.

I'm running emacs 25.4.1 on a very old HP-UX B.11.11.  I've built emacs myself using gcc 4.2.3 which is the best I can get on this box.  As far as I can tell no-one else reports a similar problem, so I'm wondering if something was amiss in the build process, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: If you temporarily `M-: (setq process-connection-type nil)` before creating the inferior process, does that make a difference? (n.b. the default is `t` and you *probably* won't want to change that default, but this is a simple way to test).

Comment: n.b. A nil `process-connection-type` means use a pipe, not a pty.  A pty will be in canonical / line-editing mode by default (`stty -F <device> -icanon` to disable that).  That provides support for special line-editing key sequences, and also imposes a maximum input size for any line (4096 bytes on my system), discarding the overflow, which which means the inferior process won't receive all the input.  Using a pipe instead of a pty avoids this 4K buffer issue, as well as any other unwanted terminal-oriented weirdness which might occur.

Comment: Thanks phils for those suggestions. I don’t have access to the machine till I return to work on Monday and I will try them then.

Comment: Setting process-connection-type to nil certainly improves matters.  I can now send function definitions to the inferior lisp process which I couldn't before.  I have to manually enter a <return> in the inf. lisp buffer for the definition to take effect, but it's much better than it was before.  Thanks again.

Comment: Great.  I think the next step would be to get this happening automatically for these specific use-cases, and probably enquire upstream as to whether it should be default behaviour.  I could possibly help with the former, but not until later in the week.

Comment: The newline issue can also be attended to -- I've done similar things for other REPLs.  This is a note to myself to also look at that.